# Facebook api access with username/password via client software

Tags: facebook, oauth

Is it possible to access the fb api programmatically with a direct nickname/password connection? If not, how else to connect to the api while maintaining it a true client application (no server running anywhere)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; you need to use one of the supported OAuth [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) flows - though there are flows there compatible with desktop apps and there's an example here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-for-desktop/

Comment: The example above clearly shows that it is possible for a Facebook user to actually get an access token they can use. Since you seem to know about Facebook a lot I would like to know the following: a) Is it not a bit un-oauth to have an access token to use unilaterally? b) Whom (which client app) does this access token belong to? Facebook itself? c) Which permissions does this virtual client app have on my account? d) Who gave these permissions? Certainly not me. e) Can Facebook get sued for this? Permissions involve authorization from the given user. As stated previously, I never gave perm.

Comment: @ChuckE so that I can understand the answer: what do you mean by "unilaterally"?

Comment: In the Oauth protocol, having app A containing resources and client B wanting to access resources, app B has to be known by app A, but in order for the app B to access resources from a resource owner in app A, app B has to establish an agreement with the resource owner from app A; the resource owner from app A agrees that app B can act on his behalf in app A. So, what I read from your script, you fetched an access token which is accessible somewhere in your facebook as you are logged in. This access token is associated with an authorization. This authorization has a set of permissions

Comment: associated (write posts, zing someone, etc...). For this authorization to exist, you, the resource owner, would have to have given authorization for this set of permissions at some given time. But apparently you didn't, and this authorization still exists, hence the access token. So, this authorization was created by Facebook unilaterally (without your authorization). And this is what currently is pissing me off as a FB user, that there is an authorization lying around which I don't know anything about.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. But why is this a problem since you can get this token only if you provide your own password? You just authenticated as yourself. Therefore the token belongs to you-the-user, no app. And of course that token has all permissions. Why should you give yourself any permission? It's redundant, you have it already.

Comment: I think these comments have gone off topic - that said, it's not possible to produce an oauth token for an app on Facebook without approving the permission set the app wants - i'm not sure how that makes it unilateral, apps can't access my data unless i explicitly approve the access they want, and they don't maintain infinite access to that data - i need to come back and continue to use the app periodically for them to maintain an active token

Comment: @Igy: but this token which is usable in the developers page, which app/client does it belong to? and who approved the permissions for it? The fact that it exists means that it belongs to a client and with a set of permissions someone (not me) approved, regardless of expiration. Fuligginoso: the password is not the issue. The token doesn't belong to you as a Facebook user, but to a registered client. That he has this token means, according to Oauth protocol, you just granted some sort of permissions on your FB account/resources. Unless this token is no Oauth token, but something else.

Comment: The token on that page is tied to the 'Developer' App which needs to be authorised at least once before you can access that part of the documentation site and/or develop apps on Facebook

Answer (score 1):

this works :) it's an ugly hack and it depends on the content of the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ page, but it does work. So why isn't there a standardized way to do it?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException,
        URISyntaxException {

    Main m = new Main();
    m.dosth();
}

public void dosth() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    String accessToken = login(Credentials.username, Credentials.password);

    System.out.println(accessToken);

}

/**
 * @param username
 * @param password
 * @return facebook access token
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws MalformedURLException
 * @throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException
 * @throws URISyntaxException
 */
public String login(String username, String password) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException,
        IOException, URISyntaxException {
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.setCssEnabled(false);
    wc.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    HtmlPage page = wc.getPage("https://www.facebook.com");
    HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page.getElementById("login_form");
    form.getInputByName("email").setValueAttribute(username);
    form.getInputByName("pass").setValueAttribute(password);
    HtmlPage home = null;
    for (DomNode node : form.getDescendants()) {
        if (node instanceof HtmlSubmitInput) {
            home = ((HtmlSubmitInput) node).click();
            break;
        }
    }

    // assume log in worked out

    HtmlPage api = wc.getPage("https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/");
    HtmlAnchor a = api.getAnchorByText("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...");
    URI href = new URI(a.getHrefAttribute());
    List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(href, "utf-8");
    for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
        if (pair.getName().equals("access_token")) {
            return pair.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

UPDATE
ok this actually doesn't work like I thought as you can get this token only after granting privileges to the "Developer" app.